# Ckeditor in xampp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor in my website.
I have ckeditor folder with ckeditor.js file in same directory as my index.html
I need to host my sites with xampp because my php files.

**Index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Responsive</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="editor"></textarea>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace("editor");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**In google chrome**
`<textarea id="editor"></textarea>` is hidden when i go `http://localhost/index.html` 
and visible when i go `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.html`

I got `ckeditor.js:835 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined` error in console

How do I fix this?

Comment: any errors in console? Any file path problems in browser dev tools network?

Comment: ckeditor.js:835 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined

Comment: I just noticed that this problem is only in chrome